# How do I tell the difference between "spaces" characters?

Tags: html, formatting, spaces

I'm having a weird issue on a page, where some space-characters seem to be non-breaking spaces, but I can't tell the difference. They just appear as " " in the html.

You can see the issue on this page: http://www.zebu.nu/forestilling/jennyandjennifer-2/

Find the 4th paragraph where it says "and makes the real world palpable". 
The space after the word "real" is causing a non-breaking space. But I can't tell why. When I inspect the code it looks like a normal space, and If i delete the space and type a new space, it fixes the issue. So I'm really confused as to why this is happening.

The intention is to have the paragraph wrap like normal text with normal spaces. How can I fix this copy's formatting?

Comment: I see. I tried making my intention a bit clearer now. Hopefully you can lift the "on hold" status.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to `&nbsp;` in your 4th paragraph.

[image]

In HTML, elements containing nothing but normal whitespace characters are considered empty. A paragraph that contains just a normal space character will have zero height. A non-breaking space(`&nbsp;`) is a special kind of whitespace character that isn't considered to be insignificant, so it can be used as content for a non-empty paragraph.

You can fix this by copying the para text and paste in a normal text editor and then copy the text from the text editor and paste it in your HTML file.

Comment: But if you look at the source code, there's no &nbsp; in there. It's all just regular spaces (" "). This is why I'm confused.

Comment: did you check with the inspect in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

That is how HTML works. Whitespace is collapsed.
To work around this, wrap your text in a < pre > tag, or use `&nbsp;` instead of space characters

refer this for complete story http://www.wikihow.com/Insert-Spaces-in-HTML

Comment: The intention is to have the paragraph break as regular text would. The issue is that it doesn't. Do adding a < pre > would only make this situation worse. Apologies, if that wasn't clear from my question